# remove special characters from a phone number

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove all the special characters in a phone number.
for ex my phone numbers look like this
`+91-5345534534`, `040-545453453`

Finally, I need all the ph numbers should be in unique format like `915345534534`, `040545453453`

I need a regular expression for this to do in php.

I am trying like this

```
$ph_number = "+91-5345534534";
filterNum = filterNum.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", $ph_number);
```

but, this is not working. Please help me in that.

Comment: Seems more like to be js code than php.

Comment: You do realise that by implementing that you have no way of distinguishing international numbers from national ones anymore? The leading `+` *is part of the phone number*.

Answer (score 12):

You are mixing up languages. The first line of code is indeed PHP, but the second is JS?

Although you are looking for the function preg_replace

```
$ph_number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $ph_number);
```

Answer (score 5):

output before-> +91-5345534534

```
$phone = preg_replace('/[^\dxX]/', '', $ph_number);
echo $phone;
```

output-> after-> 915345534534

Comment: Why `xX` in the character class?

Comment: it's nothing just remove it don't be affect that. i used because i have string like this +91-92x89XX786